# How can I plot multiple shapely polygons from list containing multiple arrays of x,y-coordinates?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, shapely

I would like to plot multiple shapely polygons in the same graph. I have the coordinates for the multiple polygons stored in multiple arrays stored in the list "labels" as shown below:

```
labels[0:2]
[array([[-30.11413383,  22.57654762],
    [-30.11402512,  22.57665825],
    [-30.11270714,  22.57665825],
    ...,
    [-30.11391449,  22.57588959],
    [-30.11391449,  22.57610893],
    [-30.11413383,  22.57632828]]),
 array([[-30.06881332,  22.57555962],
    [-30.06837463,  22.57555962],
    [-30.06815529,  22.57534027],
    ...,
    [-30.06969261,  22.57512093],
    [-30.06947136,  22.57534027],
    [-30.06903267,  22.57534027]])]
```

I am able to plot each individual element in the list "labels" separately with the code below, but I would like to plot all the elements of the list "labels" in one graph. Is there a way to do that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon as Pol_s
x,y = Pol_s(mesangium_label[1]).exterior.xy
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I may have missed something, but I don't understand why you can call Pol_s() and plt.plot() several times (as much as you need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly loop through the elements of `labels` and plot them all on the same matplotlib axes object:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for line in labels:
    x = line[:, 0]
    y = line[:, 1]
    ax.plot(x, y)
```

Alternatively you could use [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) to work with the the geometries as a `GeometryArray`. Something like this should work:

```py
import shapely.geometry, pandas as pd, geopandas
df = pd.DataFrame({'geometry': labels})
df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(shapely.geometry.LineString)
df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df)
df.plot()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to plot the arrays as enclosed polygons and color them with one color. This would make it easier to see what is the inside and outside of the polygon. I would like to plot different categories of arrays with separate colors in the same graph. Would this be possible?

Comment: Sure. Pass shapely.geometry.Polygon instead of linestring to get the polygons. Look up the geopandas plot function for arguments - you can certainly specify `color`. Feel free to ask another question by making another post